# LISP/Nyquist opening a file and reading line-by-line

Tags: lisp, audacity, nyquist

I'm struggling to open a file, and read each line until EOF.  I'm using nyquist, which is based on XLISP, and lacks Common Lisp's `with-open-file`.  My code is:

```
(let ((in_file (open "/home/soodesune/testfile.csv" :if-does-not-exist nil)))
    (loop for line = (read-line in_file)
         while line do (print line))
    (close in_file))
```

the output im getting from nyquist is:

```
error: unbound variable - LINE
```

I'd love some help understanding where I'm going wrong

---

Note:
I also tried:

```
(loop for line = (read-line in_file nil)
```

But that gives:

```
error: too many arguments
```

---

#### UPDATE:

Using the information and link that Rainer Joswig provided I was able to find typical code one might use to open a file and read it line by line:

```
  1 (do* ((fp (open "test.dat" :direction :input))
  2       (ex (read fp nil) (read fp nil)))
  3  ((null ex) (close fp) nil)
  4  (print ex))
```

The `do` function has three basic parts:

1. lines 1 and 2 - variables assigned for use in the loop, their initial values and how to increment them.  In this case `fp` and `ex`.  `fp` is not incremented, and `ex` is initialized and incremented by one `read` from from fp (I have no idea what that trailing `nil` is for)
2. line 3 - The exit condition for the loop, and a list of `return expressions` all of which are evaluated on exit, and the last of which is returned.  In this case exit will occur when `ex == null` and then `nil` will be returned
3. line 4 - The actual body of the loop.  Self explanatory in this case.

note: `do*` differs from `do` in that it allows variables assigned in one expression to be used in a later one, like how `fp` is used in the assignment of `ex`

I'm a total n00b at any kind of LISP, so if any of the above is wrong, please speak up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nyquist is not based on Common Lisp. It is based on an early XLISP. It only supports a simple LOOP and not the complex LOOP of Common Lisp.

See the Nyquist manual:

http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rbd/doc/nyquist/part19.html#226

Its LOOP syntax is:

```
(loop expr...)
```

It does not support the extended LOOP syntax of Common Lisp.